# sed replacing text in ()

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have file with lines like that:

```
90 (160/180)
```

I need to delete text in `()` including the `()`.

Output should be: `90`

This lines have different numbers, for example:

```
88 (155/190),
47 (143/188)
```

How i can do it with sed?

Comment: I guess proper question would be what kind of regex you need. There is similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521318/regex-to-remove-numbers-and-others-characters

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/ .*//'` would delete everything after the first space (before the parenthesis and onwards), and `sed 's/ ([^)]*)//'` would delete only the parenthesis and the preceding space (the expression `([^)]*)` matches a left parenthesis followed by any string not containing a right parenthesis, and then a right parenthesis).

Testing:

```
$ sed 's/ .*//' <<<"90 (160/180)"
90
```

```
$ sed 's/ ([^)]*)//' <<<"90 (160/180)"
90
```